# Uniqueness validation not working on has_many :though association on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, has-many-through, validates-uniqueness-of

**Models**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :pages, through: :memberships 
end

class Page < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :users, through: :memberships 
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :page

    validates :page_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id}
end
```

Am able to create multiple user on pages and pages on user, it's like the validation isn't getting called.

Comment: Do you mean that you can create several membership records with the same `page_id` and `user_id`?

Comment: Maybe we are saying the same thing but its hard to tell if you are expecting the correct result of that validation. You should provide a reproducable example (for example from the Rails console) where you show the result of for example `2.times { Membership.create!(user: User.first, page: Page.first) }`.

Comment: I am able to call Page.users.create name: 'user name' multiple times.

Comment: Unless you have a uniqueness validation for `User#name` that will create multiple users which is why the validation on `Membership` passes. Run `2.times { Membership.create!(user: User.first, page: Page.first) }` and you should see that it works. (as in that a RecordNotValid error is raised).

Comment: Thanks @Max, maybe am going about it the wrong way. What I would like to achieve is to NOT have same user added to a page as member multiple times.

Comment: Going through the Membership model worked, post it in the answers so we can close this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To trigger the validations in a associated model you need to use [`validates_associated`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :pages, through: :memberships
  validates_associated :memberships
end

class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  validates_associated :memberships
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :page
  validates :page_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id}
end
```

This can be a real gotcha as validations on associations are not called when they are created implicitly.

Additionally its a good idea to create a compound database index which prevents [possible race conditions](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations):

```
class AddCompoundIndexToMemberships < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_index :memberships, [:page_id, :user_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

This ensures on the DB level that no two identical rows can be created.